# Make R Shiny sidebarLayout Larger in Height

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a report in RMarkdown with shiny applications to make it interactive (using runtime: shiny in the YAML header). These applications are sandwiched with text. In this case, I have what is essentially a dashboard being sandwiched by basic text. See this image here:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to make the overall dashboard longer in height so that the user does not have to scroll up and down constantly to view stuff displayed on the sidebar or on the map below the smaller charts. In other words, can I change the dashboard and/or layout below so that the user does not have to scroll (and the entire dashboard is displayed on the page in its entirety with the text?)

Here is the fluidPage code which I suspect is where I need to change something...

```
ui2 <-  fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("year", "Years", min(my_data$years), max(my_data$years),
                  value = range(my_data$years), step= 1, sep = ""),
      selectInput("experience", "Experience level of the operators",
                  choices = unique(na.omit(my_data$experience_levels))),
      htmlOutput("summary"),
      tableOutput("table3"),
      tableOutput("table1"),
      tableOutput("table2")
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(column(4, plotOutput("plot1", width = "100%", height = "200px") ),
               column(4, plotOutput("plot3", width = "100%", height = "200px") ),
               column(4, plotOutput("plot2", width = "100%", height = "200px") ) ),
      
      
      br(),
      leafletOutput("map")
    ), 
  ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to specify `options` in the call to `shinyApp`:

`shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(height = 1300))`